# The folder you are executing pip from can no longer be found

Tags: python-2.7, pip, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a virtual machine under Hyper V that represents a cluster single-node of Hortonworks Data Platform with the following characteristics:

- OS: centos 7.6.1810 minimal
- python: 2.7.5

I installed pip package with the following command :
 `yum -y install python-pip`

The installation is well finished, but when I want to check the version of pip `pip -V` it gives me this error : **The folder you are executing pip from can no longer be found.**

My folder **/usr/local/bin/** does not contain any files or folders.

paths of python2.7 :  **/usr/bin/python2.7** /usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python

the cmd `which python` returns : `/bin/python`

**paths of pip : /usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip2 /usr/bin/pip2.7**

```
which -a pip
/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

I'm stuck thanks for helping me please.

Comment: have you tried logging out and logging back in since installing PIP?
Edit: if this works it's likely because of some environment variable that is supposed to be set at login

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I disconnected all connections and it worked very well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding it as an answer since it worked. Pip requires a log out/log in to set environment variables.

Log out and log back in, try again and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 31):

Alternatively, kill your terminal, and start a new one.

Comment: this worked for me, I guess I got tunnel vision working in the same terminal for hours

Comment: this worked for me, I guess I got tunnel vision working in the same terminal for hours